# "Starve a fever, sleep a concussion". What does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, phrase-request, expressions, translation

I'm watching an American Dad episode (S9E17), and one of the characters (Francine) say this sentence:

> Well, come on. With a head trauma like this, you should get right into
>   bed. It's like they say, **"starve a fever, sleep a concussion"**

I really don't get the meaning of this joke (i think it's a joke...), can someone help me to understand, or to translate it in French?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly - I'm not a doctor, but I would suggest that if you do feel the urge to sleep with a concussion that there's someone to look after you!

This comes from the phrase *feed a cold, starve a fever*, which expresses the belief that eating more cures a cold, eating less cures a fever.

I'm not sure how much truth there is to this, but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feed_a_cold,_starve_a_fever) has some translations, including French:

> nourrir un rhume et affamer une fièvre

With my rudimentary French, I'm sure that's a literal translation, though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is a joke.

There is an expression *Starve a fever and feed a cold*.  This comes from an old wives tale about treatment of illness.

Sleeping a concussion is a play on the saying.

Comment: Just to clarify, part of the point of this joke is it's ironic nature:  The last thing that a person with a concussion should do is to sleep, instead they should be seeking medical attention ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

This is a twist on a folk proverb “Feed a cold, starve a fever”—that is, you should eat when you have a cold, fast when you have a fever.

(Some medical authorities take issue with this, but that doesn’t come into play here.)

The joke, such as it is, is that Francine makes up a new second half of the proverb to lend authority to her immediate purpose, and betrays its factitiousness by deploying *sleep* in an unconventional sense—*sleep* is used as a transitive verb only in the phrase *sleep it **off***.

To translate it into French would require you to find a corresponding French proverb to mangle.

Comment: Additionally, there is the popularly held belief (the truth or untruth of which is irrelevant) that going to sleep with a concussion is dangerous, potentially fatal.

Comment: @Jolenealaska I'd never heard that one. That makes it even funnier, in a gruesome sort of way.

Comment: I'm really surprised that's new to you, I even remember Hawkeye saying it on MASH. Here it is debunked on [Cracked](http://www.cracked.com/article_19856_5-ridiculous-medical-myths-you-probably-believe_p2.html). I'm pretty sure the writers of American Dad were intending to reference that wives-tale.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Well, I played drums instead of football, so perhaps my mother never had occasion to cite it!

Comment: Percussion and concussion require different modals. With percussion, you *can't* sleep; with concussion, you *shouldn't* sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I'm french too, so my answer is just what came out after some searches.

I think it's a detourned version of the old adage: "Starve a fever, feed a cold.". It was a popular believe that not eating when you have a fever is bad and it make the cold worst. Today, we know that certain foodstuffs (like vitamins) help to fight disease.

In french, I can't find a similar proverb. Maybe a more or less literal translation on the tone of an adage will do the job, like "Fièvre sans manger, commotion évitée". It sound like a bullshit proverb like the original text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you guys are not aware that there is a myth that says you shouldn't sleep after a concussion. So in this case, it's a joke showing Francine is not so smart (or maybe the writers are not aware that this is just a myth)

https://www.marshfieldclinic.org/news/cattails/2014-winter-cattails/Medical-myth-busters-concussions

Comment: Welcome to ELL. This does not really answer the question. Maybe you could visit the [Help Centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before you answer another question.